# evitar que en un input type text el primer caracter sea un espacio

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando hacer la validación que tiene **whatsapp** en su *input* de tipo *text*, usando expresiones regulares. Pasa bien en la primera validación de hacer que no envie un espacio en blanco si no hay una letra primero, pero sigue buscando los espacios en blanco.

Por ejemplo: `"hola como estas"` no lo manda. `" "` no deja escribir.
`"hola"` lo manda

Este es mi código:

```javascript
    if ((/^\s/.test(inputMessage))) {
        value = ""
        console.log("no enviado")
        console.log(inputMessage.length)
      } else {
        inputMessage.trim()
        console.log(inputMessage)
        value = inputMessage
      }
```

Comment: Pues aparéntemente tu código ya funciona bien. Lo he replicado en [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/xshd8o3y/) y al ejecutarlo tal cual me entra bien en el enviado.

Answer (score 0):

La [`regular expression`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) que estas usando busca los espacios en todo el conjunto de palabras de lo que se introduzca en el input. Por eso cuando se escribe un conjunto complejo no lo enviará como mencionas por ejemplo "hola como estas".

Para solucionar esto yo comprobaría únicamente el primer carácter de la palabra y si fuera un espacio volvería a poner el input vacío. Algo como:

```js
const inpt = document.getElementById('test');

function trimSpaces () {
   if (inpt.value[0] === ' ') {
        inpt.value = '';
        console.log("no enviado")
   } else {
      inpt.value.trim()
      console.log(inpt.value)
      value = inpt.value
   }
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" oninput="trimSpaces()">
```

Comment: En verdad, si vas a hacer un [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) te sobra toda la lógica. Como indica la documentación, `trim()` elimina todos los espacios en blanco a ambos lados (es decir, al inicio y al final), con lo cual la lógica de tu método pasa a ser `inpt.value = inpt.value.trim()`. Y ya solo queda comprobar si `inpt.value.length > 0` para realizar el envío. Por cierto, `trim()` no modifica el valor del string en si mismo, si no que devuelve un string nuevo, hacer `inpt.value.trim()` en el else no sirve si no lo guarda